# assert(self.int_variable and self.int_variable != 0) is the same as assert(self.int_variable != 0)

Tags: python

I'm not too well versed with Python, but I saw in our codebase we have a bunch of assertions that look like this:

```
# int_variable is declared as an integer 
assert(self.int_variable and self.int_variable != 0)
```

The logic in the argument seems to be the same as just simply `self.int_variable != 0` or `self.int_variable` (I don't think we need both?). Is that correct, or is there something about doing this in Python that I'm not privy to?

Note that `int_variable` is declared in the class as

```
class ClassOfInterest:
  int_variable: int
```

Comment: The variable could contain a non-numeric object like an empty list which is seen as false but isn't 0 either.

Comment: If `self.int_variable` can be guaranteed to be an `int` then yes, there doesn't seem to be a reason to have both of those checks.

Comment: @matszwecja I think it is because when `int_variable` is declared in the class, it's declared as int. I'll edit that in my OP

Comment: @MichaelButscher Just edited the OP with an example of how `int_variable` is declared. In this case, it wouldn't be able to take on a non-numeric object since it's declared as an `int` right?

Comment: It's Python, it will be able to take on any object if you tell it to. Your IDE might complain, sure, but the code will run just fine.

Comment: Be aware that Python itself doesn't care about these declarations. They are processed by additional tools (mypy or an IDE).